# Create sparse file with alternate data and hole on ext3 and XFS

Tags: linux, filesystems, block

I created 1 program to create sparse file which contains alternate empty blocks and data blocks.
For example block1=empty, block2=data, block3=empty .....

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096
void *buf;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
buf=malloc(512);
memset(buf,"a",512);
int fd=0;
int i;
int sector_per_block=BLOCK_SIZE/512;
int block_count=4;
if(argc !=2 ){
        printf("Wrong usage\n USAGE: program absolute_path_to_write\n");
        _exit(-1);
}
fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0666);
if(fd <= 0){
        printf("file open failed\n");
        _exit(0);
}
while(block_count > 0){
        lseek(fd,BLOCK_SIZE,SEEK_CUR);
        block_count--;
        for(i=0;i<sector_per_block;i++)
        write(fd,buf,512);
        block_count--;
}
close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

Suppose, I create a new_sparse_file using this above code.

When I run this program, on ext3 FS with block size 4KB, `ls -lh` shows size of new_sparse_file as 16KB, while `du -h` shows 8 kb, which, I think is correct.

On xfs, block size of 4kb, `ls -lh` shows 16KB but `du -h* shows 12kb.

Why are there different kinds of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparse files is just an optimization of space, and any FS may not to create a sparse file to optimize file fragmentation and file access speed. So, you can't depend on how spare the file will be on some FS.

So, 12kb on XFS is correct too.

Comment: In the same program, I increased the block_count so that 200MB of file is written. ls -lh shows 200MB for both FSs but du -h shows 187MB on XFS and 100MB on ext3. Some much difference to optimize file fragmentation and file access speed?

Comment: try not to fill a lot with minimal sized block of 4kb, but increase a block size. I mean change `#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096` into `#define BLOCK_SIZE (4096*32)`

Comment: Yes, increasing block size would work, but it won't create a file such that there is 1blockhole,1blockdata,1blockhole,1blockdata.... type of sequence.

Comment: xfs is not block-based fs, but a extent-based. So, size of extent can be bigger than single block.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in XFS :

http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2011-06/msg00225.html